# Building a high-current battery test system with Raspberry - Need component and implementation advice

Tags: battery, analog-to-digital

I'm designing a battery test system to charge and discharge a 26.7V battery pack with a maximum discharge current of 60A. We have a load bank and a charger. The system should: Charge the battery to full for 2 hours. Wait 30 minutes. Discharge at 60 A for about 40 minutes while logging current, voltage, and temperature. Cutoff when reaching 21 V or when reaching too high a temperature Wait for 2 hours. Restart cycle, I also want to collect and log various data points about the battery pack during testing. I'm planning to use a Raspberry Pi for data acquisition and control, but I need some guidance on the following: High-current switching: Which components are suitable for handling such high currents for charging and discharging? Should I consider high-current MOSFETs, smart relays, or other options? Data acquisition: What sensors can I use to measure voltage, current, temperature, and other relevant parameters? How do I interface them with the Raspberry Pi for data collection? Software and control: Can anyone recommend libraries or frameworks for controlling the charging/discharging process and logging data on a Raspberry Pi? Safety considerations: How can I ensure safe operation of the system while working with high voltages and currents? What safety measures and circuit protection should I implement? I have some experience with electronics and programming, but I'm particularly interested in learning from the community's expertise in building high-current battery test systems. Any advice, recommendations, or existing project references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Should I consider high-current MOSFETs, smart relays, or other options?` ... that is not a question about the Raspberry Pi

Comment: please focus your post to one answerable question that is about the Raspberry Pi

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)